# How to return the list with the specified number of elements removed from the front of the list

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I'm writing a function in Haskell that recursively returns the list with the specified number of elements removed from the front of the list. I've gotten it to work doing this:

```
removefront :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removefront n xs =
    if n <= 0 then xs
    else removefront (n-1) (tail xs)
```

This works and does exactly what I want however is there a way to do the same thing without the tail function. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this function is "built in" in the sense that it is in the prelude and called drop

```
*Main> :t drop
drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
*Main> drop 3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[4,5,6,7]
```

now, I will assume that is not the answer you were looking for.  You can easily modify your function to not use tail.  The trick is to use pattern matching.

```
removefront :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
removefront n (x:xs) = if n <= 0 then (x:xs) else removefront (n-1) xs
```

three notes

1. Most Haskeller would not use `if then else` for such a function, preferring guards

   ```
   removefront n (x:xs) 
      | n <= 0    = (x:xs)
      | otherwise = removefront (n-1) xs
   ```
2. The type of `removefront` can be much more general

   ```
   removefront :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
   ```

   actually it could be all the way to

   ```
   removefront :: (Num i, Ord i) => i -> [a] -> [a]
   ```

   but that is getting excessive
3. you should consider what happens when you hand your function the empty list--what do you want it to do?

Comment: i'm aware of the built in drop function. I'm essentially attempting to write my own drop function of sorts. 
I'm pretty much new at Haskell so I'm not too familiar with patten matching and how to use it

Comment: detailed explanation* & i added a condition to handle the empty list. thanks again